# Can't add integer to List<Integer>

Tags: java, jpa, integer

I have problem with the below code. If I use resultList to add integer, it stays null. If I use preresult to add integer, it works but gives error when returning result. I couldn't find a way to get this single result.

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
@ApiMethod(name = "getDate")
public List<Integer> getDate() {

    List<Integer> preresult = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> resultList = null;

    try {
        Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        int CurrentDayOfYear = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        Integer intObj = new Integer(CurrentDayOfYear);
        preresult.add(intObj);


    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return preresult;
}
```

Comment: As-is, this code works and returns a list of one element. If you just change `preresult.add(intObj)` by `resultList.add(intObj)`, you will get a `NullPointerException` because `resultList == null`. I don't understand "it works but gives error when returning result". Can you be more explicit on which error and what you expect ?

Comment: @savante What is your mgr doing there? Why are you not using it yet closing it? `mgr.close()`

Comment: @user3437460 right, forgot it there. Removed.. I will check your solution right away. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you only created an empty variable pointing to null for resultList.

Change:

```
ArrayList<Integer> resultList = null;
```

To:

```
ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: I left it there to show the attemps I did. You didn't even read the question, did you?

Comment: If `mgr` is null then there should be a NPE...

Comment: @DennisW You didn't even bother to read the description, did you? OP mentioned `If I use resultList to add integer, it stays null`. With the limited code snippet given, this is the advise I can give to OP. You can post your solution below if you think there is something wrong with mine and I think it is not right to down vote someone's solution without looking at the codes and description properly.